# app crashing and getting error: Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm trying to delete all objects of type "Lead", using realm, I tried using this code:

```
 RLMResults<Lead *> *allLeads = [Lead allObjects];
    for (RLMObject *object in allLeads) {
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm deleteObject:object];
        }];
        [realm refresh];
    }
```

after using this app is crashing and I'm getting this error when I'm trying to reload the tableView :

```
 if (!obj->_row.is_attached()) {
        @throw RLMException(@"Object has been deleted or invalidated.");
    }
```

UPDATE: 
I tried the following, but also didn't work, it deletes everything, but it crashes also, I found that the problem is in the [tableview reloadData] :

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm deleteAllObjects];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: You should be using Collection Notifications, if you did then this wouldn't happen

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of with Realm is that if you retain an `RLMObject`, and then delete it, the reference you retained earlier will still be present in memory, but obviously the underlying backing data has been deleted.

For example:

```c
// Get the first Lead object
Lead *firstLead = [Lead allObjects].firstObject;

// Delete it from the Realm in which it is stored
[firstLead.realm transactionWithBlock:^{
   [firstLead.realm deleteObject:firstLead];
}];

// Try to read data after it was deleted
NSString *name = firstLead.someString; // Will throw the RLMException
```

Even though trying to access any of the persisted properties will trigger the exception, you can avoid this by checking if `firstLead.invalidated` is `YES` before attempting to do so.

Basically, if your table view is retaining any objects (ie, maybe you assigned a `Lead` object to each cell), you need to go through and completely remove any references to any of those objects. You should be able to see in the exception call stack which deleted object was trying to be called again. This reference needs to be removed at the same time the objects are deleted, or simply have `invalidated` checked beforehand.

Additionally, in regards to your code above, there is a more performant way to write it.

```c
RLMResults<Lead *> *allLeads = [Lead allObjects];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
   [realm deleteObjects:allLeads];
}];
```

In Realm, best practice is to minimize the number of write transactions you need to perform. In your example, you're opening and closing a transaction on each iteration of the `for` loop. The example I posted above only performs one for all of the objects. :)